# java: how to read a txt file to an Array of strings

Tags: java

Hi i want to read a txt file with N lines and the result put it in an Array of strings.

Comment: Now we know what you want, what is your question? :)

Comment: Here's some alternatives ( they just need a little tweak )  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file

Comment: And another: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/ReadLinesFromFile.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [`java.util.List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
  lines.add(sc.nextLine());
}

String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: this is the answer, thanks men :)

Comment: @Enrique: read the API about how `Scanner` handles `IOException`.

Comment: How to print all elements of String[] arr?

Comment: you can use a for over an array, in eclipse you can use the autocomplete fuction for an example like: https://ideone.com/ZMTesT

Answer (score 6):

```
FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/filename"));
```

From [apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

This will get you a `List` of `String`. You can use `List.toArray()` to convert, but I'd suggest staying with `List`.

Comment: looks like this method is deprecated now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [the Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)?

For example:

```
Path file = ...;
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = file.newInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
} finally {
    if (in != null) in.close();
}
```

Comment: yeah, i read the java tutorial and others books, this don't resolve the problem because i want to put all the lines of the file in an Array of strings like:

    String [] content = new String[lenght_of_the_string];


    int i = 0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null {
        content[i] = line;
        i++;
    }

Answer (score -1):

Set up a `BufferedReader` to read from the file, then pick up lines from from the buffer however many times.