# Converting object value to string array

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

so I have been trying to convert an object value to string array. basically I'm using stringtokenizer to get the strings from a text file, so I can search for specific values. I am using this library first time. so any help wold be appreciated. here is my main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] keys = {"she","sells","sea","shells","by","the","sea","shore"};      
        In in = new In("Protein.txt");
        TST<Integer> st = new TST<Integer>();
        String text1;
        String string = "";
        String [] line1;
        while ((text1 = in.readLine()) != null) {

           String line = text1.trim();
           //System.out.println(line);

           StringTokenizer stt = new StringTokenizer(line);
           while (stt.hasMoreElements()) {
               //System.out.println(stt.nextElement());
               string = String.valueOf(stt.nextElement());
               //line1 = string.split("");
               System.out.println(string);              
           }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: No error. I am able to convert object value to string as 'string = String.valueOf(stt.nextElement());'. what I need to do is to convert object value to string array. but i don't know how to do it. I searched it but couldn't find any help

Comment: Ok. Are you looking for other options? Can you please elaborate more on the question?

Comment: Yes. i can use jsoup but I don't know its working. how it converts text file into string array.

Comment: right now I just want to convert text file into string array. It would be very helpful if u could guide me to the right path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2977109/6032482 ...................this will healp u in converting text file into string array

Comment: An array can only take elements up-to a predefined size, you need a List to add all the token. You can then convert it into an array.

Comment: So you want to convert text file into array?

Comment: Mehraj malik.......Yes

Answer (score 0):

While reading each line as strings put them in an List. We can invoke toArray after reading all the lines.

Other Options is you can use [readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) from File Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache's FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to work with `File`s.

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

There are more useful methods like `readLines`, you can use `List<String>` instead `String[]` like below :

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("myfile.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);
```